# The "This post has been edited 1 time" banner doesn't disappear when changing pages on review queues

Tags: bug, review-queues, design, notifications

The banner that appears when a post you are editing has been edited by someone else doesn't disappear when on a review queue and you change the page.  (IE click "save edit").  I would expect it to do so when I advance away from that review item, since I am no longer on that post.  (I believe that it does so on other pages).

While I didn't manage to grab a screenshot of it on other pages, I did manage to get one of another bug: If, on that next page, you dismiss the notification with its <kbd>x</kbd> button, the page doesn't scroll up properly and you are left with a white space at the top:

> [image: The whitespace at the top should have disappeared when I dismissed the notification]
>   *That white space was not a side effect of bad screenshots; it was part of the page*

The two bugs:

- When one receives the "This post has been edited 1 time, your edit must be more thorough to save it" (or something like that) notification while editing a post in a queue, the notification does not disappear when proceeding to the next item.
- When on a page other than the page that one was on when the message appeared, closing the message with its <kbd>x</kbd> button results in white space remaining at the top of the page.  This disappears on refresh.

  - This may apply to closing it at any point in the review queue; I don't encounter that message much which makes it hard to be certain.

This occurred in the 'First Posts' queue.  I use Internet Explorer 11 for my browser (11.0.9600.17416 (Update 11.0.14 KB3003057)) under Windows 8.1, if that is important.

Comment: The same happened for me.  I'm running Chrome 42.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: Happens to me with Firefox 60.4.0 as well