# "This post has been edited x time since you began" persists after saving the question

Tags: bug, review-queues

In the Suggested Edits queue, I was editing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345217/diagonalization-of-a-tridiagonal-symmetric-sparse-matrix-with-python), and this nice message (that someone else had already edited it) appeared. Helpful, of course.

Only, after I had saved the edit, and moved to the [next post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17403703), the message was still present, even though I was not editing the next post, and doubt someone else had edited it. When switching to history view, it disappeared, and didn't reappear when I switched back to the post.

Please just make that message be gone after saving the edit and moving to the next post. Now it's just weird, and if I want to edit the next one, I probably can't see if someone else has edited that (because the message is already there).

Setup: Windows 7, Chrome 61.0.3163.91, no plugins

Comment: Potentially related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278019/the-this-post-has-been-edited-1-time-banner-doesnt-disappear-when-changing-pa and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347844/this-post-has-been-edited-2-times-since-you-began-your-edit-can-only-be-saved-i

Comment: Reproduced. It seems like simply running `StackExchange.notify.close(-2)` every time a new review item is loaded should cleanly remove the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in the comments above, the problem is that, while the [review code](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/review.en.js) does remove other kinds of popups by calling `StackExchange.helpers.removeMessages()` whenever a new review item is loaded, that doesn't actually get rid of this particular type of notification bar.  To do that, the code should also call `StackExchange.notify.close(-2)`.

As of the latest version (v1.50), my [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script includes [a fix for this bug](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/68cdb600b9a0e4901790585259216567ed548e33/SOUP.user.js#L1579) that simply runs the missing function call when it detects that a new review item has been loaded.